# How to set enum attribute by value instead of name in Android Layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, enums, android-databinding

I have one custom view holding another one. Hierarchy:

```
MyOuterView
->MyInnerView
```

`MyInnerView` has an enum attribute like:

```
<attr name="myAttr" format="enum">
    <enum name="foo" value="0"/>
    <enum name="bar" value="1"/>
</attr>
```

So I can instantiate the component in `MyOuterView` XML like:

```
<com.example.MyInnerView
....
app:myAttr="foo"/>
```

Which works of course.
The `MyOuterView` offers an argument for customization itself. Based on this argument I want to set the argument of the `MyInnerView`.

The wished behavior is that I can work with Data Binding like:

```
<com.example.MyInnerView
....
app:myAttr="@{data.getMyAttr()}"/>
```

where `getMyAttr()` looks like:

```
public int getMyAttr() {
    return myAttr; // returns 0 or 1
}
```

The result is a compile issue.

> ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:myAttr' with parameter type int on
>   com.example.MyInnerView

So obviously I can't set the enum by value but only by name. Any idea besides creating the `MyInnerView` programmatically? Please note that I can't change `MyInnerView`.

Comment: you can define another attribute, which will do the same thing, but accept integers instead of enum

Comment: good point, however for reasons I can't change MyInnerView.

Comment: then unfortunately I see no other way except creating it programmatically. Or using a setter after it has been created from xml

Comment: thx for your recommendations!

Comment: Is the attr initialized only in constructor or there is a setter for the inner view which accepts enum? In the latter case you could use binding adapter, which accepts int as a parameter and then convert it into enum and set using that setter.

Comment: @rom4ek You're right. In case there's a setter on the inner view a binding adapter usage like `bind:myAttr="@{data.getMyAttr()}"` would be a working solution. If you want to put it as an answer I will accept it until there's a solution without this workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can't set the enum by value but only by name

That is not entirely true. You wouldn't be able to set the value with DataBinding even by name, the thing is that the value of an attribute defined in an xml is passed to the `View` through the constructor. A `View` could have both an attribute and a setter but that's not necessarily the case. For instance, is you set a value for `android:text` of a `TextView`, that value is set to `com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextView_text` which is then retrieved from the `AttributeSet` in the constructor. If you use DataBinding, `setText()` is called, but these are 2 completely different things, the feature is the same but they're not related in the code.

Given that you can't modify `MyInnerView` and that there is no setter you can call for `myAttr`, your only option is to pass it through the constructor. DataBinding is simply not feasible, even with a BinderAdapter you wouldn't be able to set the value in the `AttributeSet` because the `View` is already instantiated at that point.

**Option 1 - themes**

Define a new attribute

```
<attr name="MyInnerViewAttrValue" format="integer" />
```

Then resolve this attribute with a style, for instance you could have

```
<style name="AppTheme.Foo">
    <item name="MyInnerViewAttrValue">0</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Bar">
    <item name="MyInnerViewAttrValue">1</item>
</style>
```

Set it in the layout xml

```
<com.example.MyInnerView
    ...
    app:myAttr="?attr/MyInnerViewAttrValue" />
```

And then call `setTheme(int)` in the `Activity` before the views are instantiated.

**Option 2 - custom BindingAdapter**

If you wanted to set your value DataBinding (because you had a setter, or because you wanted to hack `MyInnerView` with reflection) then you would need to create a custom BindingAdapter, for instance

```
@BindingAdapter("myAttrValue")
public static void setMyAttr(MyInnerView myInnerView, int value) {
    switch (value) {
        case 0:
            myInnerView.foo();
            break;
        default:
            myInnerView.bar();
    }
}
```

Then in the layout xml

```
<com.example.lelloman.dummy.MyInnerView
    ...
    myAttrValue="@{model.attr}" />
```

And give the `int` value from your ViewModel

```
public class MyInnerViewModel {

    public int getAttr() {
        return 1234;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can use attribute name like  `app:myAttr="@{...}"` only if there is setter for that and this setter is mapped to attribute name or can be resolved by its name.
In your case, if this attribute is used only in View's constructor and view has not any public method for change this - you still have a few possible solution:
- extend View and implement logic to customize view like this attribute do (if possible)
- make BindingAdapter and use Reflection (if possible).
- create your own view by copy-paste and fix)